# Displaying response in Codeceptjs - API

Tags: node.js, codeceptjs

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to ask this question somewhere else. That said, please excuse me if I'm using this site wrong.

As for my question, is there a way on how to display the response of the API using codeceptjs? I've recently learned about the 'I.say()', however I'm not quite sure how to get the proper response and actually put it in there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the expected output is a JSON (or whatever result as seen in Postman) as I'm using Codeceptjs with the API alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Basically, I added the 'async' in the Scenario, and then added a variable, being equal to the I.sendGetRequest with an 'await' before it.